# TreeTableView: Cell Format dependent on another column (TornadoFx)

Tags: tornadofx, cell-formatting

I have a treeTableView defined in TornadoFx

```
treeTableView = TreeTableView<EntityItem>().apply {
        column("Id", EntityItem::id).prefWidth(200).cellFormat {
            //how to refer to value of property Name ?
        }
        column("Name", EntityItem::name).prefWidth(200)
```

I want to format the cell 'Id' dependent on the value of the property/column 'Name'

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the item for the current row using the `rowItem` property. This might be null, so make sure you access it with the null safe operator (?).